# Does a place without gravity exist in the universe?

Tags: gravity, universe

Is there a place in the universe far enough from existing matter to consider that there is no gravity field ? Does the behavior of matter in such a place would differ from what we see in the ISS (falling forever) ? What does the trajectory of an object look like in such a place ?

Comment: No gravity field, or a point where the magnitude of that field is 0?  The latter is satisfied by a Lagrange point.  The former may only be found in truly exotic situations where the concept of gravity breaks down.

Comment: Well, if you are in a free moving frame there is no gravity. 
e.g. If you jump from a window (don't do it) you will not experience any gravity as long as you are falling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without finding one, we don't know for sure, and if we did, I don't know how we'd recognize it, but one of the basic principles of gravity in theory is that gravitational forces exist between *every* pair of objects in the universe. Gravitational acceleration, then, exists at every point in the universe if there is any matter at all.

However, there does exist the potential for *net* gravitational acceleration to be equal to zero. Acceleration is a vector, and as such acceleration equal in magnitude but opposite in direction would net out to zero. Or three or more might combine to form a net of zero. Given the above principle, it would probably be impossible to say for certain whether any point is *exactly* zero in a universe with more matter than we could possibly take into account, but in theory, such points could exist.

The precedent is laid down in the concept of [Lagrangian points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point), points in a two-body system where net gravitational acceleration is matched perfectly by the centripetal acceleration required for the point to retain its relationship to the bodies. This is not exactly what you're looking for, but demonstrates how gravitational acceleration via multiple bodies can net out to a value less in magnitude than either individual acceleration.

There are five such points, L1 through L5. But even so, external bodies not counted in the model would still exert gravitational force on anything placed in those points. It would be assumed negligibly small but technically speaking would still exist. It may be possible that there are points somewhere in the universe where, at least momentarily, net gravitational acceleration is zero because all the accelerations from every object in the universe sum to zero, but again I don't know how we would recognize this situation if it ever occurred.

On the second part of your question, about the trajectory of an object in space free of gravity, no such situation could exist. To my knowledge, the only way to have a region of space greater than a single point with no gravity whatsoever is to have no matter in the universe. If you added an object to check its trajectory, there would no longer be no gravity.

This might seem like a meaningless nitpick since the object won't affect its own trajectory, but spacetime itself would be affected (this is what gravity *is*, afterall).

Supposing we did have a universe with no matter, what we would find is that spacetime would be completely flat. Just like this:

[image: Flat space]

If we could somehow add a non-object with no mass, it would simply stay in one place forever. If we gave it a push, it would continue in a straight line forever. Of course, in any practical sense, there would be no difference between the stationary object and the one moving in a straight line, and in a universe with completely flat spacetime, neither space nor time would seem very familiar to us, and we wouldn't have a reference for either.

The good news is that for practical purposes, space is so big that there are plenty of places you could go that would *seem* like there is no gravity. Between galaxies, for example, gravitational acceleration would seem to be non-existent because of the vast amount of space. We can tell that we are experiencing gravity here on Earth because we are constantly pushing down on the Earth. We can tell that we are experiencing gravity in free fall because we can see the ground approaching. But out there, where it's lightyears and lightyears to the nearest object, you could be careening through the universe at thousands of miles per hour, but how would you know?

Comment: +1 so, to dig out the oldest joke in the book,you are saying gravity is not just a good idea. It's the law......

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on how you define a "gravity field". 
But it also depends on how crude you approximate or what situation you are interested in. Usually space between galaxies (or even stars) is assumed to be empty when considering questions in cosmology. But since there is also a lot of stuff in the intergalactic medium (ultra low density dust?), for some questions this can not be assumed to vanish (e.g. trying to figure out how this dust behaves). But the density is so low that it can be assumed to vanish for considering the kind of physics we know from every day life (e.g. assuming frictionless motion of heavy macro objects because you approximate the space to be empty).

On the other hand, you raise a very good point. You can do a coordinate transformation (in Newtonian Physics as well as in General Relativity) into the reference frame of the object you are interested in. In a few (not all though, please correct me if i am wrong) situations this equals to transforming the away the gravitational field. Therefore the behavior of matter in "empty space" would equal that of an freely falling object, meaning you can transform its motion away and find a frame in which it is not moving.

On a third hand, there are always quantum fluctuations in space. So it is never "really empty", but the associated gravitational field would probably be way too small to really effect anything macroscopic. (Actually, i dont know whether the gravitational aspects of quantum fluctuations are understood since that sounds a lot like it should be treated within a working theory of quantum gravity which does not exist yet).

Comment: You can assume flat inertial space in a small enough region, but you can't remove gravity for **all** observers. No coordinate transformation can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter how far away from an object you are, there will always be at least some infinitesimal force of gravity acting on you by the object.  The force of gravity existing between you and an object is related to the inverse of distance between the two of you.  If you are 9 times farther away, the force is 81 times smaller.  100 times farther away, the force is 10 000 times smaller, and you get the picture.  But there is always some force, since you can't divide a number by any number, no matter how large, to obtain a quotient of zero.

Now, it's important to keep in mind that mankind's current understanding of science is still incredibly low.  We don't even know what 96% of the stuff in the universe is.  So there could be regions were the laws of physics play out differently, but according to our current understanding, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

To a good approximation, the strength of gravity falls off with the distance from matter squared.  So there is no place in the universe where the strength of the gravitational field is literally zero because there is always some distance to matter.  In between galaxies, it is very small though, so to a high degree of accuracy objects move as if there is no gravitational field, meaning that whatever direction they're traveling in they continue traveling in that direction at the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that such a region exists, but there may be regions where the effective gravitational force is minimised ,because of the mass (and energy) distribution surrounding  the low gravity region is symmetrical.

Gravity, like electromagnetic radiation, is theoretically infinite in range, but detection of such small forces would difficult.

Deviations from a given trajectory would be equally difficult to measure.